# Why doesn't this expression filter in my Value Relation?

Tags: qgis, filter

Why won't this filter expression work?
I have followed all the examples I can find but it allows no items to pass through the filter.

[image: [1]]

Comment: You might need to show us a sample of your dataset - it's hard to tell just from what you've provided alone. Maybe there's leading or trailing spaces in one of your values so it doesn't match exactly?

Comment: Maybe the Attribute "Feature" in the Filter expression is not the Attribute you want to filter with, since it's also your Key column. If you show us the structure of your "Wellsite Features" layer, maybe we can help.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  It does not appear that you can filter on your key column.  Thank you.